# How can I create multiple intersecting circles?

Tags: jquery, raphael, geometry

[image]

I would like to make a circle image like this and animate it. Is it possible using Raphael? If so can any one give some good ideas on how you can do this. I am going to implement this into a responsive layout. Is that possible?

To do this, dose any one have a simple calculation?

Comment: I am not able to get the shape at all.. i don't have idea..

Comment: you need to get on - http://raphaeljs.com/ they show you how to do circles on the home page, start getting some circles then color them then come back when you are stuck

Comment: Of course it's possible -- not just possible but quite easy.   http://voidblossom.com/tests/intersectingCircles.php I love Raphael!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set fill color of circles in semi-transparent rgba format:

```
{fill: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)}
```